# Intercepting event binding using Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am working on our mobile site and there is a requirement to intercept the click event which calls a particular number

```
<a id="callUs" href="tel:xxxxxx">asdad</a>
```

Before the call is made, I need to perform some custom operation and then let the call continue.

for this I am doing the following

```
$j(document).bind("pageinit", function(e, data) {
$j('#callUs').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('asdasd');
    custom_function('xxx');
    $j(this).trigger('click');
});
});
```

Obviously this goes into an infinite loop since the trigger in the last line is intercepted again on and on.

```
$j(document).bind("pageinit", function(e, data) {
$j('#callUs').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('asdasd');
    custom_function('xxx');
    $j(this).unbind('click').trigger('click');
});
});
```

However, when I unbind the event as shown above, the call is not placed.

Any thoughts for how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Is $j a modern shortcut for jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#callUs").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        custom_function('xxx');
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    });
});
```